# Removing hash sign using Jquery Adress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash

`Jquery Adress Plugin` automatically add an hash sign **(#)** to the url. Is there a way to remove it and still have the deep linking functiunalities ?

Or is there another way to do Ajax deep linking without the hash sign.

I've looked at the HTML5 History API which is not adding hash sign but then when I refresh the page I get a **404 error.**

Which seems normal because all my app is using `Ajax` and the URL Im using are "fake" (created by me).

Hope you understand what Im trying to explain.. my english is far from perfect.

Thanks

Comment: Well your server needs to know how to handle those URLs. Look into URL rewriting.

Comment: @epascarello : Is it the only way ? With `Angularjs` you can do it without taking care of url rewriting

Comment: Angularjs uses URL rewriting...http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes_html5-mode_server-side

Comment: Ok this is true. So Im gonna look at url rewriting. Thanks